# Какая разница между 'is' и '==' в Python?

Tags: python, if

В чём разница между 'is' и '==' в if, и есть ли она вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рискну привести такое - краткое, но зато очень простое объяснение:

оператор `==` проверяет равенство значений двух объектов

оператор `is` проверяет идентичность самих объектов. Его используют, чтобы удостовериться, что переменные указывают на один и тот же объект в памяти

Обратной стороной краткости ответа является то, что есть собенность: для экономии памяти, булевы типы, числа и строки могут кешироваться. Это означает, что при заведении двух *разных*, но равных между собой строк и `str1==str2` и `str1 is str2` будут `True`.

Answer (score -2):

В нормальных языках (со статической типизацией) обычно is определяет, принадлежит ли объект какому-то классу, например, классу Student:

if(object is Student)
(object as Student).GetFirstName()

а == - это булевый оператор "равен", он определяет, ссылается ли объект на ту же область памяти, если это ссылочный тип, либо имеет то же значение, если это тип значения.

Comment: Мысль про то, что означает "is" в "нормальных языках" тоже пришла мне в голову. Но в Питончике этот оператор имеет дугой смысл. Кроме того, даже в "нормальных языках" для ссылочных типов сравнение "==" ведет себя сложнее (см https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#reference-type-equality-operators). Мне кажется, Вы слишком упростили ответ. Но минусовал его не я :-)